# CoroutineWorker and coroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

In the documentation for the `CoroutineWorker` I found a snippet of the `doWork` method:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
...
}
```

Is the `coroutineScope {` necessary? What happens if I don't use it and then one coroutine is cancelled? Will the `CoroutineWorker` still work?

I'm using the WorkManager and I have implemented the `CoroutineWorker` without creating a new scope. I sometimes see that the job after having run periodically for a while, stops running.
Can that be the cause? I can `try` but even if it works I'd like to be sure that I know why it is working and why the documentation uses that code snippet.

Comment: In their sample, it says something weird of "Calls setForegroundAsync() periodically when it needs to update the ongoing Notification" : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running … . Might be related?